# MenuItems with different styles

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

Is it possible on Android to have MenuItems (either the ones from the options menu hardware key or action bar -- they are the same anyways) with different styles?

I want one to have a selector applied and another with different selector.

From my search online, I found that you can change the theme and override an attribute with your own style, but that applies to ALL MenuItems.

Can I still set the `android:background` property in XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible for items of the `ActionBar`. You have to define the item that you want to have a different selector as a custom action view.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_custom"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/action_view"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

In the layout referenced by `android:actionLayout` you have an `ImageView` that you assign your selector and make it clickable and focusable.

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/action_view_background"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:minWidth="56dip"
    android:paddingBottom="8dip"
    android:paddingTop="8dip"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

The click event is not handled by `onOptionsItemSelected`. You have to attach an `OnClickListener` in `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

```
menu.findItem(R.id.menu_custom).getActionView().setOnClickListener(l);
```

Comment: While a bit hacky I'll take it!

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683186/menuitems-checked-state-is-not-shown-correctly-by-its-icon)

> *According to the official document at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#checkable*
>
> *Note: Menu items in the Icon Menu (from the Options Menu) cannot display a checkbox or radio button. If you choose to make items in the Icon Menu checkable, you must manually indicate the checked state by swapping the icon and/or text each time the state changes.*

The same is applied to action bar items, since it's the same object, MenuItem

Comment: I was not referring to checkable or not, but this might lead me to the answer. Care to post some code sample?

Comment: What it means with checkable or not, is that MenuItem's doesn't have a internal state that can be represented by a selector. Because of this, you have to manually keep track if the button was pressed or not and change the icon accordingly.