# Switch for onPrepareOptionsMenu

Tags: java, android

How can I write this switch statement? I want make two statements for the items below.

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
switch(?????){
case ?????:

    }
}

MenuItem log = menu.findItem(R.id.action_Log);
log.setChecked(isChecked);

MenuItem sound = menu.findItem(R.id.action_Sound);
sound.setChecked(isChecked);
```

Comment: so you want to handle the click event on menu items? Did you create the menu in xml and inflated in using `onCreateOptionsMenu`?

Comment: I want both items to be checked.

Comment: your question was not clear, even after I asked you about it here in the comments. Why do you want to use a switch statement?

Comment: this questions addresses your porblem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683186/menuitems-checked-state-is-not-shown-correctly-by-its-icon

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know when the menu item is clicked you need to implement `MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener` in your `Activity` then override the method `onMenuItemClick` like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_Log:
            // do stuff
            return true;
        case R.id.action_Sound:
            //do stuff
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I used this method allready. I just want both items to be checked.