# Selected tab's color in Bottom Navigation View

Tags: android, material-design, navigationbar

I'm adding a `BottomNavigationView` to a project, and I would like to have a different text (and icon tint) color for the selected tab (to achieve greying out non-selected tabs effect). Using a different color with `android:state_selected="true"` in a color selector resource file doesn't seem to work. I also tried having additional item entries with `android:state_focused="true"` or `android:state_enabled="true"`, no effect unfortunately. Also tried setting the `state_selected` attribute to false (explicitly) for the default (non-selected) color, with no luck.

Here is how I add the view to my layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/silver"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bnv_tab_item_foreground"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bnv_tab_item_foreground"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_bar_menu" />
```

Here is my color selector (`bnv_tab_item_foreground.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"  />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
</selector>
```

And my menu resource (`bottom_nav_bar_menu.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_taxi_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_rides"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_airport_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/rides"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_cafes"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_cafe_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/cafes"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_hotels"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_hotel_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/hotels"/>

</menu>
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 376, accepted):

While making a `selector`, always keep the default state at the end, otherwise only default state would be used. You need to reorder the items in your selector as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"  />
</selector>
```

And the state to be used with `BottomNavigationBar` is `state_checked` not `state_selected`.

Comment: add it on 
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
/>

Comment: In my case I needed to generate dynamic menu, and this solution didn't work. The only working solution was manually setting menu items http://stackoverflow.com/a/7106111/2098878

Comment: What about divider in between of items ?

Comment: "state_checked not state_selected". What a time saver:) Thanks!

Comment: On KitKat, the default selector flashes when selected and creates visual inconsistencies.

Comment: the order is important!

Comment: add it on <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_color_state" app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_color_state" /> instead of @ drawable

Comment: For anyone who got stuck like me, I had to create a "color" directory in "res" , and put this file in there.

Answer (score 108):

**1.** Inside **res** create folder with name color (like drawable)

**2.** Right click on color folder. Select 
*new-> color resource file-> create color.xml file* (bnv_tab_item_foreground) 
*(Figure 1: File Structure)*

**3.** Copy and paste bnv_tab_item_foreground

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            app:itemBackground="@color/appcolor"//diffrent color
            app:itemIconTint="@color/bnv_tab_item_foreground" //inside folder 2 diff colors
            app:itemTextColor="@color/bnv_tab_item_foreground"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

bnv_tab_item_foreground:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/white" />
        <item android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"  />
    </selector>
```

**Figure 1: File Structure:**

[image: Figure 1: File Structure]

Answer (score 74):

`BottomNavigationView` uses *colorPrimary* from the theme applied for the selected tab and it [uses](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView.java#L159) `android:textColorSecondary` for the inactive tab icon tint.

So you can create a style with the prefered primary color and set it as a theme to your `BottomNavigationView` in an xml layout file.

*styles.xml*:

```
 <style name="BottomNavigationTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/active_tab_color</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/inactive_tab_color</item>
 </style>
```

*your_layout.xml*:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            android:theme="@style/BottomNavigationTheme"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Comment: `android:textColorSecondary` not works. should use `android:colorForeground` instead

Comment: This is the best answer, the "selector" method uses "darker_gray" as the inactive tab color which is different form the original one. Also `android:textColorSecondary` works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

If you want to change icon and text colors programmatically:

```
ColorStateList iconColorStates = new ColorStateList(
     new int[][]{
          new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_checked},
          new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked}
     },
     new int[]{
          Color.parseColor("#123456"),
          Color.parseColor("#654321")
     });

navigation.setItemIconTintList(iconColorStates);
navigation.setItemTextColor(iconColorStates);
```

Comment: you made my day :) Works like a charm

Answer (score 19):

I am using a `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView` (not the same as OP's) and I tried a variety of the suggested solutions above, but the only thing that worked was setting `app:itemBackground` and `app:itemIconTint` to  my selector color worked for me.

```
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            style="@style/BottomNavigationView"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:theme="@style/BottomNavigationView"
            app:itemBackground="@color/tab_color"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/tab_color"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_text_color"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />
```

My `color/tab_color.xml` uses `android:state_checked`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/grassSelected" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/grassBackground" />
</selector>
```

and I am also using a selected state color for `color/bottom_navigation_text_color.xml`

[image]

Not totally relevant here but for full transparency, my `BottomNavigationView` style is as follows:

```
    <style name="BottomNavigationView" parent="Widget.Design.BottomNavigationView">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/bottom_navigation_height</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">bottom</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/bottom_navigation_text_size</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: color/tab_color.xml? Can you explain.

Comment: I posted `color/tab_color.xml` in my answer above, it is the color selector file.

Answer (score 10):

It's too late to answer but might be helpful for someone.
I was doing a very silly mistake, I was using a selector file named as **bottom_color_nav.xml** for Select and unselect color change but still it was not reflecting any color change in BottomNavigationView.

Then I realize, I was returning **false** in **onNavigationItemSelected** method. It will work fine if you'll return true in this method.

Comment: I spent almost 30 minutes , tried every sol , 
Finally got to know I was returning False and that was my mistake

Answer (score 7):

In order to set textColor, `BottomNavigationView` has two **style properties** you can set directly from the xml:

- `itemTextAppearanceActive`
- `itemTextAppearanceInactive`

In your layout.xml file:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bnvMainNavigation"
            style="@style/NavigationView"/>
```

In your styles.xml file:

```
    <style name="NavigationView" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView">
      <item name="itemTextAppearanceActive">@style/ActiveText</item>
      <item name="itemTextAppearanceInactive">@style/InactiveText</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ActiveText">
      <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
    <style name="InactiveText">
      <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBaseBlack</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Not sure why I couldn't get this solution to work, but the accepted solution did work. Also anyone looking for the default material styling of `itemIconTint` and `itemTextColor` , check out `@color/mtrl_navigation_bar_item_tint`

Answer (score 3):

Try using `android:state_enabled` rather than `android:state_selected` for the selector item attributes.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I tried state_enabled as well, but that's not the correct state attribute to be used with this specific widget. The issue was what was mentioned in the answer: 1. The ordering was wrong (default state should be the last item in the selector) 2. state_checked is the correct state attribute to be used with BottomNavigationView.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
setItemBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_red_light)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the folder structure has changed, the `tab_color.xml` belongs to `res > drawable`  now which can handle selectors. From there on the accepted solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating selector,
Best way to create a style.

```
<style name="AppTheme.BottomBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item> 
</style>
```

and to change the text size, selected or non selected.

```
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_text_size" tools:override="true">11sp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size" tools:override="true">12sp</dimen>
```

Enjoy Android!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView` as your XML view and want to achieve this same selector as a dynamic/programmatically, then use this

```
val bottomNavSelectorStates = arrayOf(
                intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_selected),//selected
                intArrayOf(-android.R.attr.state_selected),//default/un-selected
            )


val colors = intArrayOf(
                ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.blue), ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black)
            )


bottomNavigationView.itemIconTintList =
                ColorStateList(bottomNavSelectorStates, colors)
            bottomNavigationView.itemTextColor =
                ColorStateList(bottomNavSelectorStates, colors)
```