# BottomNavigationView Original icon color

Tags: android, android-menu, android-bottom-nav-view

I have my bottomNavigationView :

[image]

And i added this class to prevent it from doing shiftingMode :

```
public class BottomNavigationViewHelper {
    public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        try {
            Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setShiftingMode(false);
                // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                //item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
        }
    }
```

I just want to show the original icons colors without this selector, how i can reach this ?

my navigation xml :

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_item"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You have to make your item icon tint list `null`, You reach that from your bootomNav :

```
bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it works!  I tried adding: app:itemIconTint="@null" to the XML, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why does this work?  I figured my app:itemIconTint might be the problem, but when I omit that attr from the XML the unselected icons don't show up at all unless I also call setItemIconTintList(null).  How is calling setItemIconTintList(null) different from not specifying an icon tint at all?

Answer (score 7):

Our use case was a multicolored icon when the tab is active and a grey one when it is not. Setting `itemIconTintList` to null made the inactive tab icons have the same colors as the active ones when using the material component `BottomNavigationView`.

[image: BottomNavigationView]

So we had to do this in addition:

**menu_bottom_navigation.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/first_tab"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_first_tab_selector"
        android:title="@string/first_tab_title"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/second_tab"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_second_tab_selector"
        android:title="@string/second_tab_title"/>
</menu>
```

**ic_first_tab_selector.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_first_tab_inactive" android:state_selected="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_first_tab_active" android:state_selected="true" />
</selector>
```

Where `ic_first_tab_inactive.xml` is the drawable for your inactive icon and `ic_first_tab_active.xml` is the drawable for your active icon.

Comment: Thank you, you saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 3):

Here How you would do if you are using Kotlin Find your navigation Id From your Main Activity then in your mainActivity onCreat Use This Code

```
 my_navigation_item.itemIconTintList = null
```

Comment: Your explanation is unclear and doesn't seem to add anything to [this accepted and upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44516194/9209546).

Answer (score 1):

You are able to use `app:itemIconTint` from `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

For example

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    //...
    app:itemIconTint="@color/gray_scale"
    //...
/>
```

It is handy when your drawables have different colors

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer worked but that method is now deprecated.

The new way to enable the original icon colors is:

```
bottomNavigation.setForceTint(false);
```