# Bottom Navigation Icons dont show original color

Tags: android, material-design, android-bottomnav

I downloaded some .png files for icons. I designed a bottom navigation of material design but the colors and text is not visible. Here's a picture of icons and bottom nav.
[image: icons]

[image: home_fragment]

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_catalogue"
    android:icon="@drawable/catalogue"
    android:title="Catalogue" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    android:title="Search" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_achievement"
    android:icon="@drawable/achievement"
    android:title="Achievements" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
    android:icon="@drawable/testaccount"
    android:title="Profile" />
```

Home Activity

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
   
    navView.setItemIconTintList(null);
  
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.navigation_catalogue, R.id.navigation_search, R.id.navigation_achievement,R.id.navigation_profile)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
}

}

 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:itemIconTint="@null"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In this post you can find a solution for your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57861254/how-to-change-a-specific-icon-image-from-bottom-navigation-view

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515664/bottomnavigationview-original-icon-color

Comment: I've updated the code. It's still not working

Answer (score 2):

Add `app:itemIconTint="@null"` in your `BottomNavigationView`

Comment: I tried in my android studio and it is working, will you please share your updated code?

Comment: will you try to do it in XML, add this: app:itemIconTint="@null", I mentioned in the answer also.

Answer (score 0):

In your respective java or kotlin class
`binding.bottomNav.itemIconTintList = null`
use this property it works for me (bottomNav will be your bottom navigation).