# Android: Bottom Navigation View - change icon of selected item not working

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I want to change the selected item whole icon not the tint color in bottom navigation view.I have the selector for each icon but i don't know where to add that image selector. Please any one tell me the solution.

**Code:**

```
private void handleBottomNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
        case R.id.action_calendar:
            switchFragment(new PatientAppointmentStatusFragment(), "TODAY");
            break;
        case R.id.action_case_sheets:
            switchFragment(new CaseSheetFragment(), "Case Sheet");
            break;
        case R.id.action_history:
            switchFragment(new HistoryFragment(), "History");
            break;
        case R.id.action_reports:
            switchFragment(new ReportsFragment(), "Reports");
            break;
        case R.id.action_billing:
            switchFragment(new BillingFragment(), "Billing");
            break;

    }
}
```

**Menu**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_calendar"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_calendar_bg"
        android:title="@string/menu_calendar"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_case_sheets"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_case_sheets_bg"
        android:title="@string/menu_case_sheets"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_history"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_history_bg"
        android:title="@string/menu_history"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_reports"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_reports_bg"
        android:title="@string/menu_reports"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_billing"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_billing_bg"
        android:title="@string/menu_billing"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText" />

</menu>
```

Here is the code for bottom navigation view xml.

```
<BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/tab_background"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/navigation_item_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/navigation_item_color"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
```

I tried the following link but it's not working for me.

Link [Android: Bottom Navigation View - change icon of selected item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41826122/android-bottom-navigation-view-change-icon-of-selected-item)

Comment: follow this. https://materialdoc.com/components/bottom-navigation/

Comment: will you please tell me what is " navigation_item_color" Is it file or color name?

Comment: @PRIYAPARASHAR icon and text selector color

Comment: @Radhey Any idea about to change different icon for the selected item ?

Comment: what is your expected output and what are you currently getting! pl attach screens.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a folder **color** in **res** folder .Into **res/color** folder create a file with ***"navigation_item_color"*** name and use following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--state is enabled and checked-->
    <item android:color="@color/white"  android:state_enabled="true" android:state_checked="true" />
    <!--state is enabled and not checked-->
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_checked="false" />
    <!--state (menu item) is disabled -->
    <!--   <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/light_black"  />-->
</selector>
```

Comment: Hi already i am using like that only. I want to change whole icon item

Comment: It means you want to change the icon of all list item.

Comment: I want to replace the selected item with different icon not the tint color.

Comment: for replacing the icon then you may use @drawable/ instead of @color/

Comment: Ya i tried that it's not working. Do you have any code for that ?

Comment: drawable

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_billing_un_selected" android:state_checked="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_billing_selected" android:state_checked="true" />
</selector>

Comment: let me try ,After that i'll tell you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155240/discussion-between-shanmugapriyan-m-and-priya-parashar).

Comment: Hello there did u try that ?

Comment: @Priya Parashar Thank you for this answer. Even though this doesn't answer the actual question asked. I could find my answer. For some strange reason, selector file for color needs to be in its own folder named color and selector file for drawable needs to be in drawable folder.