# Changing options menu icon in bottomNavigationView depending on an open Fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment

Option Menu:

```
    <item  
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="Home"/>

    <item  
        android:id="@+id/companies"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_companies"
        android:title="Companies"/>

    <item  
        android:id="@+id/contact"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_contacts"
        android:title="Contact"/>
```

I want to change this item's icon programmatically depending on the open Fragment and, obviously, have different actions when the user hits this button. I tried several things to do that, but nothing worked.

The last thing I tried was this code in my `Fragment` `onCreateView` method:

```
Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
menu.findItem(R.id.ic_home).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home_fill);
```

but its not work for me.

what i tried in  `selectFragment(MenuItem item)`

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.home:
                 item.setIcon(R.id.ic_home_fill);
                break;
            }
```

I want to change the icon of the bottom navigation of selected position. if user clicked one item then the icon change to another one and when i select another one then 1st icon can set as a default.

refer this link:[Android: Bottom Navigation View - change icon of selected item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41826122/android-bottom-navigation-view-change-icon-of-selected-item)
but it's not work for me

plz give me a other solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, It worked for me

```
BottomNavigationView mBottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
mBottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.click_to_use:
                           addHomeFragment(MainActivity.this);
                            mTitle.setText("Home");
                            item.setIcon(R.drawable.device);
                            break;
                        case R.id.history:
                           addNotifyFragment(MainActivity.this);
                            mTitle.setText("History");
                            item.setIcon(R.drawable.ios_icon);

                            break;
                        case R.id.settings:
                          addSettingFragment(MainActivity.this);
                            mTitle.setText("Settings");
                            break;
                    }

                    return true;

                }
            });
```

Comment: it's not work for me error show : `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.crm/com.example.crm.dashBoard}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.Menu.findItem(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: If you are using still this code Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
menu.findItem(R.id.ic_home).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home_fill); then in this you are using wrong ID .findItem(R.id.ic_home) you have to pass view id .findItem(R.id.home)

Comment: I have also edited my code you can also use mbottomnavigationview directly insteadof using menu

Answer (score 0):

after any modification in the menu, you would have to make an "Invalidateoptionsmenu ()" in the action. I invite you to want to test this feature .  [see here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu())

Comment: sorry i can't understand what do u mean?

Comment: add invalidateoptionsmenu() before the return of onNavigationItemSelected()  .

Comment: please refer to the documentation that I give you .

Comment: not work for me bro 
See my question bro i change the icon perfectly but when i select second icon then 1st icon was change as a default but it's not

Comment: If you need save data permanente ,you need to save it in shared preferences. and read from it .

Comment: no no i don't want to store a data it's simple designing issue