# Bottom navigation view - gradient icon tint

Tags: android, material-design, gradient, bottomnavigationview

I have changed icon tint in BottomNavigationView using selector and gradient color as tint when icon is pressed, but instead changing icon tint to gradient Android made all my icon purple. 
[image]
My question is if there is any possibility to change tint of icons in BottomNavigationView to be gradient color?

BottomNavigationCode:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_bottom_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_menu_background"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

bottom_menu_background:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:color="@color/button_gradient_blue" android:state_checked="true" />
     <item android:color="@color/baseGray"/>
 </selector>
```

button_gradient_blue:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/base_button_radius" />
            <gradient android:angle="0" android:startColor="@color/light_blue_gradient_start"
            android:endColor="@color/light_blue_gradient_end"  />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/base_button_radius" />
            <solid android:color="@color/button_pressed_color"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/base_button_radius" />
            <gradient android:angle="0" android:startColor="@color/light_blue_gradient_start"
            android:endColor="@color/light_blue_gradient_end" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I managed to do this by using two different drawables, one with gradient tint and one for unselected in Bottom Navigation Menu.

I have created custom view that extends form BottomNavigationView, and I have created custom method for creating menu:

```
fun initMenu(){
    itemIconTintList = null
    var firstStart = true
    setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        val index = it.itemId
        firstStart = false
        menu.forEach {
            if (it.isChecked && !firstStart) {
                if (it.itemId == index)
                    return
                it.isChecked = false
                it.icon = ContextCompat
                    .getDrawable(context, UNSELECTED_MAP[it.itemId]!!)
        }

    }
    it.icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, SELECTED_MAP[it.itemId]!!)

}
```

Where UNSELECTED_MAP and SELECTED MAP are a HashMaps with item menu id as "key" and drawable resource as "value"

Comment: @kacper can you please provide a detailed answer to this. I am also in the same situation and unable to figure out what  to do

Comment: @TarunKumar Sure, I have followed answers [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41826122/android-bottom-navigation-view-change-icon-of-selected-item) , if you still be facing this problem let me know, so I will copy my code here

Comment: @KacperKogut, I have icon selected state icon with gradient and different icon for unselected state. But as I need to provide the icontint attribute in else, the icon is appearing white and the icontint attribute is not accepting gradient drawable. So I am unable to set the gradient icon in the  bottomnavbar. I need to  know how you achieved to set the gradient icon on the selected state.\

Comment: @TarunKumar, You can't do it this way. You have to create drawable for selected and for unselected state, and when user press the icon you have to change drawable not the color. I updated my anwser to show you how I did it

Comment: @KacperKogut thanks a lot for your help. Now it's working

Answer (score 3):

A more simple way to achieve this than creating a subclass is to create two separate drawable, then create a selector assigned as the icon for the menu for the bottom navigation view.

activity.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/sel_navigation"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/sel_navigation_label"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

menu/navigation.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_history"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_history_selector"
    android:title="@string/title_history" />
</menu>
```

drawable/ic_history_selector.xml:

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_history_selected" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_history_selected" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_history"/>
</selector>
```

drawable/ic_history.xml:

```
<vector ...>
<path android:fillColor="@color/gradient_orange" .../>
</vector>
```

color/gradient_orange.xml:

```
<gradient xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:angle="0"
android:endColor="@color/orange"
android:startColor="@color/lightOrange"
android:startX="0"
android:endX="0"
android:startY="0"
android:endY="100"
android:type="linear" />
```

Finally, you need to set the icon tint list to null, so it won't use the icon tint color from the XML. Works perfectly with gradients (API 24+).

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47203888

Comment: Where is the sel_navigation xml class

Comment: It is a regular color selector. 

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/orange" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/orange" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/darkGray"/>
</selector>

Answer (score 0):

set color in java
`bottomNav.addItemNav(new ItemNav(this, R.drawable.ic_home, getResources().getString(R.string.home)).addColorAtive(R.color.yellow_selected_color).addColorInative(R.color.text_color));`