# Navbar does not update correctly with onbackPressed fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I recently implemented the onBackPressed method on my fragments, this works well but there is a little bug with my nav bar...

Pictures are better than a long speech !

In this picture : The app is launched

[image: the app is launched]

In this picture : I clicked to the last button on the right (Infos)

[image: I was on the first button on the left (The map) then i clicked the last button on the right (Infos)]

In this picture : I want to go back on the first fonctionnality (The map) so i clicked on the return key

[image: I want to go back on the first fonctionnality (The map) so i clicked on the return key]

As you can see, in the last screen the good fragment is displayed but the button "Infos" of the nav bar is still clicked !

This is my code to launch the fragments :

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_profile:
                        AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
                        if(token ==null) {
                            selectedFragment = new EnregistrementFragment();
                            //selectedFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                        }else{
                            selectedFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                        }
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_map:
                        selectedFragment = new LocalisationFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_group:
                        selectedFragment = new ScoreFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_faq:
                        selectedFragment = new InfosFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_favorite:
                        selectedFragment = new FavoriteFragment();
                        break;
                }
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack("FirstFragment");
                transaction.commit();

                return true;
            }
        };
```

And my method onBackPressed() :

```
    public void onBackPressed() {
    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        //additional code
    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

My question is : Have you an idea to refresh the navbar ?

Thank you in advance and really sorry for the bad english !

Comment: Did you check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41826560/10530566 ?

Comment: I have read your link and i don't think this is the same problem, i don't want to change my icon i just want to update the nav bar when i use the return key

Comment: Did you check out this link: ! https://stackoverflow.com/a/43117486/10530566

Comment: Not yet i'm going to see this :)