# BottomNavigationView set selected item background color programmatically

Tags: android, android-bottomnav

I know we can set the bottom navigation selection color from XML in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52234495/13572333) way

But I want to know how we can change it programmatically from my Activity?

This is what I tried in Activity's `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`.

```
 item.getIcon().setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorBrown));
```

Also tried to change tint list like this:

```
item.setIconTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimaryBlue)));
```

Here is the complete snippet of my code:

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = item -> {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigationTask:
                    item.getIcon().setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorBrown));
                fragment = new MyTaskFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.navigationProfile:
                    item.setIconTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimaryBlue)));
                fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.navigationRequest:
                fragment = new RequestListFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.navigationMore:
                fragment = new MoreFragment();
                break;
        }
        loadFragment(fragment);
        return true;
    };
```

but it's not working for me. Any ideas or reference link on how to change this programmatically will be helpful for me.

Note: I want to change only the selected item's icon and text tint color. Not the entire items in the bottom navigation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(....)
```

and use a selector (not a single color):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:alpha="1.0" android:color="@color/..." android:state_checked="true"/> 
  <item android:alpha="0.6" android:color="@color/..."/>
</selector>
```

[image]
[image]

If you want to do it programmatically:

```
    int[][] states = new int[][] {
        new int[] { android.R.attr.state_checked}, // state_checked
        new int[] { }  // 
    };

    int[] colors = new int[] {
        color,
        color2
    };

    ColorStateList myColorList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
    bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(myColorList);
```

Comment: I tried this but it is effecting all the items in the bottom navigation. I want to change only the selected one.

Comment: @SnehaMudhigonda it happens because you are not using a selector.

Comment: Yes, I used that but how can change those drawable colors programmatically?

Comment: @SnehaMudhigonda in this case you have to build a ColorStateList programmatically. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Use `setItemTextColor` for the text color and `setItemIconTintList` for the icon

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I tried your updated answer it is effecting only text color but not icon tint color.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score -1):

Here is @Gabriel's answer in Kotlin:

```
val states = arrayOf(
                intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_checked),
                intArrayOf()
            )
    
val colors = intArrayOf(
                selectedColor,
                unselectedColor
            )

val myColorStateList = ColorStateList(states, colors)
bottomNavigationView.itemIconTintList = myColorStateList
bottomNavigationView.itemTextColor = myColorStateList
```