# How to Set selected item in BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to set default item on activity created but it isn't working?
This is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_userhome);
    mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    profile = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.profile);
    mall = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mall);
    dietplan =(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.dietplan);
    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) 
    findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.dietplan);
     navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener 
    (mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
}
```

But it seems that `navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.dietplan);` is not working.  Please help me to set default item of bottom navigation bar:

This is my stack trace(logcat):

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: gym.android.ommsoftware.gym, PID: 1915
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{gym.android.ommsoftware.gym/gym.android.ommsoftware.gym.Userhome}: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at gym.android.ommsoftware.gym.Userhome.onCreate(Userhome.java:57)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: sad, nobody knows why...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just share my working source code

In Xml,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:id="@+id/gfPrlBnvBtmView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In Java,

```
  public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{
    private BottomNavigationView mBtmView;
    private int mMenuId;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        mBtmView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.gfPrlBnvBtmView);
        mBtmView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        mBtmView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_yoga).setChecked(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        // uncheck the other items.
        mMenuId = item.getItemId();
        for (int i = 0; i < mBtmView.getMenu().size(); i++) {
            MenuItem menuItem = mBtmView.getMenu().getItem(i);
            boolean isChecked = menuItem.getItemId() == item.getItemId();
            menuItem.setChecked(isChecked);
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_food: {
            }
            break;
            case R.id.action_medical: {
            }
            break;
            case R.id.action_yoga: {
            }
            break;
            case R.id.action_postures: {
            }
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: if someone down vote pls explain why  then only i change my answer, thanks

Comment: why you checking all menu? You can do it like this `item.setChecked(true);`.

Answer (score 63):

Instead of selected you need to `setChecked(true)` that item.  Try this code

```
mBottomNavigationView=(BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
mBottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.item_id).setChecked(true);
```

Checked item is highlighted in `BottomNavigationView`.

Comment: i have tried this before navigation.getMenu().findItem(R.id.dietplan).setChecked(true); but it  gives NullPointerException

Comment: firstly initialise bottom_nav then find menu.. its working code ... I tried this

Comment: How do I change the color of the checked item?

Comment: @AlanNelson check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40326245/7130121

Comment: Note this only highlights the item but does not click it.

Answer (score 12):

### Kotlin Solution

In a Fragment

```
getActivity()?.myNavigationViewId?.selectedItemId = R.id.other_tab_id
```

In an Activity

```
myNavigationViewId?.selectedItemId = R.id.other_tab_id
```

> NOTE: Make sure to replace `myNavigationViewId` and `other_tab_id` with your actual navigation view and tab ids.

Answer (score 9):

FYI: for fragment, onCreateView

```
BottomNavigationView mBottomNavigationView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);

mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.your_item);
```

Comment: thank you for this! I kept getting a NPE. I needed your `getActivity()` in order to execute the `findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav)` because I was doing it from a fragment. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Kotlin extension version of [Abshishek's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43246106/3736955) answer:

```
internal fun BottomNavigationView.checkItem(actionId: Int) {
    menu.findItem(actionId)?.isChecked = true
}

// use 
bottom_navigation.checkItem(R.id.navigation_home)
```

This does not trigger `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`.

Answer (score 4):

Kotlin solution with Fragment

```
var fragment = Fragment()
bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav)
bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
  when (item.itemId) {
    R.id.home -> {
      fragment = HomeForm()
    }
    R.id.score -> {
      fragment = ScoreForm()
    }
  }
  supportFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment)
    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
    .commit()
  true
}
bottomNav.selectedItemId = R.id.score // init open score tab
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also set selection in BottomNavigatioView using index like this :

```
public void selectBottomNavigationOption(int index) {
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                index = R.id.action_1;
                break;
            case 1:
                index = R.id.action_2;
                break;
            case 2:
                index = R.id.action_3;
                break;
            case 3:
                index = R.id.action_4;
                break;
        }
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(index);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
    navigationView?.menu?.findItem(drawableMenuItem.id)?.isChecked = true
```

and it will not fire `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` events.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

**Activity layout:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/tabs"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/tabs"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
```

**color/tabs.xml:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="@color/not_active" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:color="@color/active" android:state_checked="true"/>

</selector>
```

**Click callback:**

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_tab0:
            setFragment(f0);
            break;
        case R.id.action_tab1:
            setFragment(f1);
            break;
    }
    return true; // not false!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add **`android:enabled="true"`** to your BottomNavigation menu items.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_id"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_my_icon"
    android:title="@string/menu_title"/>
</menu>
```

And in `onCreate()` method,
set up listeners by
 `bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mListener)`.

And set the desired item to be selected by doing `bottomNavigationView.selectedItemId = R.id.menu_id`.

This will trigger `onNavigationItemSelected()` from the `NavigationItemSelectedListener` whenever the activity is created.

Answer (score 0):

There are two senario

> Set the selected menu item ID. This behaves the same as tapping on an item.

Code example:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(myNavigationItemListener);
bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.my_menu_item_id);
```

> I you only need to check it without tapping

Code example:

```
  BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView= (getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_manage_orders_id).setChecked(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, `setSelectedItemId(int id)` only showed the fragment, but selected menu item was still the wrong one.

I figured out that calling `setSelectedItemId(int id)` after the `BottomNavigationView` is all set up is not enough.

I stopped calling `setSelectedItemId(int id)` in `onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)` and started calling it in `onResume()` instead. That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I should be like below in case if you are using with navigation component and want all control.

```
  private fun setupDashboard() {
    binding.navBottomHome.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.dashboardFragment -> {
                findNavController(viewId = R.id.dashboardNavGraph).navigate(R.id.dashboardFragment)
                binding.navBottomHome.isSelected = true
            }
            R.id.ordersFragment -> {
                findNavController(viewId = R.id.dashboardNavGraph).navigate(R.id.ordersFragment)
                binding.navBottomHome.isSelected = true
            }
            R.id.productsFragment -> {
                findNavController(viewId = R.id.dashboardNavGraph).navigate(R.id.productsFragment)
                binding.navBottomHome.isSelected = true
            }
            else -> {
                findNavController(viewId = R.id.dashboardNavGraph).navigate(R.id.settingsFragment)
                binding.navBottomHome.isSelected = true
            }
        }
        Log.d("TAG++", "Item selected")
        true
    }
}
```

in short setting the listener and setting `binding.navBottomHome.isSelected = true` works.

Answer (score -1):

If what you want is that the clicked element is ignored on the view and is not returned as "selected" you can return false after the click is handled, in some cases and some designs you could need to open an activity instead of a fragment and this will make selected the bottom item after the activity is closed.

```
private val onNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.navigation_shipment -> {
            currentItem = TAB_INDEX_SHIPMENT
            val intent = Intent(this, BookShipmentActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener false
        }
    }
    false
}
```