# Bottom navigation view doesn't handle back botton action

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, back-button-control

I'm new in android programming and sorry for my poor english
In my android app there is a bottom navigation with 5 items
They work great but i have a problem with back button
Imagine item 2 is showing its fragment and when user press back button item 1 fragment's is shows but in bottom navigation item 2 seems to be running 
How could i fix this bug?
Thanks

Comment: This could help you!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43246059/how-to-set-selected-item-in-bottomnavigationview

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways:

- You could handle the `onBackPressed` on the activity then set the current page for `bottomnavigationview`
- Check the current page of the `viewpager` then set current item for the `bottomnavigationview`

Comment: Also i don't use view pager

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this
mBottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);

here getItem(0) will be count of bottom navigation view item