# navigation menu item not highlighted on switch of fragment1 to fragment2 with button click in fragment1

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I have two fragments in my app namely HomeFragment and FeedbackFragment. In addition to switching fragments on tab buttons, I would also need to switch between fragments on a button click that is within the fragment. The tab items are highlighted properly on switching fragments using tab clicks. But the tab items does not get highlighted when i switch to other fragment on a button click from fragment1

Below is the code used to switch across fragments on button click and it works.

```
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =  getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

But the respective tab icon of FeedbackFragment is not highlighted. Currently the navigation item of HomeFragment remains highlighted even after FeedbackFragment is replaced. How do I highlight the menu item of Feedback Fragment  ?

I tried below approaches but nothing worked:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)   findViewById(R.id.navigation);

View view = bottomNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.tab_calls);
view.performClick();
```

Also,

```
  MainActivity.mBottomBar.selectTabAtPosition(2);
```

Nothing worked. Please help.

Comment: look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43246393/2849550) may help you

Answer (score 0):

Try using the method to select a tab as if it was tapped:

```
bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.tab_calls)
```

Comment: Yes, I did try all of this, but of no use :(          The given examples are to highlight the tab item icon on click of tab items. But  In my case I want to highlight the bottomNavigationView item on button click from another fragment. The highlighting of item works perfectly fine, when i click on the tab item to switch across fragments. But I would need to switch on fragments from a local button within my fragment. In such cases am not able to access bottomNavigationView that is available in MainActivity from my fragment.

Comment: Have you found the solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

What I have done now is in onResume of each fragment I try to de highlight all other tab bars and highlight the current tab bar again. I access the bottomNavigationMenu from each fragment and do this. Not sure if this is the right way to handle it but it works atleast.