# How to not change Bottom Navigation View Item Color on click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, bottomnavigationview

I have three items in my `bottomNavigationView`

[image]

When I click on the profile item the code checks whether the person is logged in or not. If the person is not logged in then I need to start a new `Activity` else I need to load a `fragment` in my `frameLayout`.

Now the problem is that when I click on the profile item and the person is not logged in then the activity starts but when I click back then the profile item is highlighted but the home fragment is loaded in the frame layout.

[image]

I have tried the following ways to solve this

1) I used `setSelectedItemId` to set the item color when profile item is clicked but it didn't work

Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: Have you tried putting    
setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener listener)

Set a listener that will be notified when the currently selected bottom navigation item is reselected.

Comment: this is how you can know which menu is clicked and then change its color using
 setItemIconTintList(ColorStateList tint)

Comment: @vikaskumar I am not reselecting the item. I am on the Home item and then i click on the Profile Item.

Comment: @vikaskumar i also need to highlight the item whose fragment is currently loaded.

Comment: can you post your code for above, here i can't tell where you are going wrong.  what i am getting is you are trying to check weather user has logged in or not then open a activity or a fragment. but if you place a profile tab in navigation it is suppossed to open some fragment anyway. you can check your condition either in adapter or some where before opening third tab. you can place  listener posted above to know which menu item clicked and then make logic there to open activity or profile. And open home fragment if user is not logged in.

Comment: @ANUJGUPTA you can check my answer.

Answer (score 7):

I finally figured out how to do this and i am sharing it here

**You need to return false if you don't want to change the item's color**

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.action_home:
                            HomeFragment fav_frag = new HomeFragment();
                            currentFragment = fav_frag;
                            loadfragment(fav_frag);
                            break;
                        case R.id.action_designers:
                          break;
                        case R.id.action_profile:
                            if(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(BaseActivity.this).getString("customer_id","").equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                                Intent intent=new Intent(BaseActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("Target","Profile");
                                startActivity(intent);
                                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up,R.anim.stable);
// Here is the key , you need to return false when you don't want to change the items color
                                return false;
                            }else {
                                ProfileFragment accountFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                                currentFragment=accountFragment;
                                loadfragment(accountFragment);

                            }


                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hi ANUJ GUPTA !    You can try my answer.It's more easier.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

**Add `selector` to your code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/black" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

**Then add your xml code.**

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector_navigation"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector_navigation"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"/>
```

**Note**

```
// icon 
app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector_navigation"
// text
app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector_navigation"
```

Comment: This is the best approach. More details here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325422/selected-tabs-color-in-bottom-navigation-view

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/toolbar_background"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nac_color"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nac_color"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
```

here `@color/bottom_nac_color` is the color you want to display on screen

HOPE It works

Answer (score 0):

you can change by java code like this.

UPDATE:

```
 bottomNav.addItemNav(new ItemNav(this, R.drawable.ic_home, getResources().getString(R.string.home)).addColorAtive(R.color.yellow_selected_color).addColorInative(R.color.text_color));
```

Answer (score 0):

`return false` thats it because for launching activity we need not to higlight menu item

Answer (score 0):

probably you use switch in **onNavigationItemSelected** for your bottom navigation and you return true for in end of every case you have.

for every item that you don't want to change their colors, return false and for change color when user click on item return true.

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.one:
                    // your code
                    return true; // on click will change color
                case R.id.two:
                    // your code 
                    return false; // on click will not change color
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```