# Setting checked and unchecked state for bottom navigation bar not working [Android]

Tags: android, material-design

I am creating an app in which I created a bottom navigation bar. Now what I want is to set separate colors for selected/unselected state of nav bar items. So I created an xml file and set it for item tint and text color for navigation bar as shown:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
        <item android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"  />
</selector>
```

and in main menu adding navigation bar as:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/mainNav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_bar_item_state"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_bar_item_state"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_items"></android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
```

I got this solution from this link:

[Selected tab's color in Bottom Navigation View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325422/selected-tabs-color-in-bottom-navigation-view?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

But when I run the app it crashes with error "unable to inflate navigation bar". What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**
I tried the same thing by creating selector file in drawable file but unfortunately it also doesn't work.

Comment: Hey , follow the link given you will get the idea ,HAPPY COADING https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-navigation/

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:-**
    Set `item.setCheckable(true)` inside `onNavigationItemSelected()`

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.navigation_home:
            item.setCheckable(true);
            mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```