# different items background in BottomNavigation

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav, android-bottom-nav-view

I'm trying to customise my BottomNavigationBar.

[image: De]

I set tabs' shape and color by specifying common itemBackground to BottomNavigatoinBar, but I'd like different tabs to have different colors.

Is there a way to set the background for each element separately?

Here is Navigation code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorTransparent"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/round_blue"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorWhite"
        />
```

Comment: Hope you help this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325422/selected-tabs-color-in-bottom-navigation-view)